# String Date to DateTime Format

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a string with a value of 13/12/17,09:37:20+32 I cant convert it in datetime format. Error always occur saying that the "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime". This is my code:

```
 DateTime crtdDate = DateTime.ParseExact(l.CreateDate, "yy/MM/dd,hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Please someone help me.Thanks!

Comment: What is `+32` supposed to be?  That's certainly not a valid timezone offset.

Comment: You date is in invalid format try make it something like this 2013/12/17,09:37:20+32 instead of 13/12/17,09:37:20+32 because 13 is interpreted as month 13.  And code to DateTime crtdDate = Convert.ToDateTime(d);

Answer (score 1):

`tt` represents either `am` or `pm`

+32 won't be parsed by tt. If you are trying to parse hundreths of a second, try `ff`.

```
var  crtdDate = DateTime.ParseExact(l.CreateDate, "yy/MM/dd,hh:mm:ss+ff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: +32 is your timezome value

Comment: Never seen it, but the closest thing I can find in the format spec is `zz` which specifies **hours** offset from UTC. Why would someone need to offset by more than 12 hours?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: Me either, but it does automatically reduce the date to 1 day before the date specified.  c# does something about the other bits (this were just my speculations)

Answer (score 0):

Your string must match the format exactly:

```
 l.CreateDate = "06/15/2008";

 [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx][1]
 "d" -> 6/15/2009 1:45:30 PM -> 6/15/2009 (en-US)
        6/15/2009 1:45:30 PM -> 15/06/2009 (fr-FR)
        6/15/2009 1:45:30 PM -> 2009/06/15 (ja-JP)



 DateTime.ParseExact(l.CreateDate, "d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Without the +32, this will parse:

```
 DateTime.ParseExact("13/12/17,09:37:20", "yy/MM/dd,hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Use a valid timezone specifier, the following will work:

```
 DateTime crtdDate = DateTime.ParseExact("13/12/17,09:37:20+00:00", "yy/MM/dd,hh:mm:ssK", 
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```